# Solving probability given conditional probability function.

Tags: probability

Every member of an insured group has an annual claim amount distribution that is exponentially distributed.
The expected claim amount of a randomly chosen member of the group is $\frac{1}{c}$, where $c$ is uniformly distributed between 1 and 2.
Find the probability that a randomly chosen member of the group has annual claim less than 1.

The answer is $$P(X<1|c)=1-e^{-c}\Rightarrow$$
$$P(X<1)=\int_1^2P(X<1|c)\cdot f(c)dc=\int_1^2(1-e^{-c})dc=0.767$$
but I don't understand it, particularly the second part. I see that $\int_1^2P(X<1|c)\cdot f(c)dc=P(C<1\cap c)$ but I don't see why this is the answer.

Comment: It's basically a continuous version of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). You have the probability given $c$, but as $c$ is itself random, to find the true overall probability, you need to average this out, weighted by the distribution on $c$. As a single formula, the idea is that $P(A)=E_c(P(A\vert c))$. (in this case, the event $A$ is that $X<1$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They tell you that $C\sim \text{unif}(1,2)$. Recall the density of $C$ is
$$f_C(c) = 1.$$ Once you know $C$, the **expected** claim amount is $\frac{1}{c}$. This means that the parameter of the exponential distribution is $\mu = c$, so that $X|C\sim \text{Exp}(\mu = C)$, and the density is
$$f_{X|C}(x|c) = ce^{-c x},$$ with cdf 
$$F_{X|c}(x|c) = P(X<x|C=c) = 1-e^{-c x}.$$
So finally, 
\begin{align*}
P(X<1) &= \int_1^2 P(X<1| C= 1)f_C(1)\,dc\\
&= \int_1^2F_{X|C}(x|1)f_C(1)\,dc\\
&=\int_1^2 (1- e^{-1\cdot x})\cdot1\,dc.
\end{align*}